# How to execute a javascript function above two columns and return as a third column?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I had an webpage that compares two .docx file and returns the lines where the files don't match.
I want to create a diff column where the diff between the strings(I may handle the return as strings) are 'highlighted'.
My html page is renderized by django in the following way:

```
<table class="table" border="1px">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Arquivo Original</th>
          <th scope="col">Arquivo Secundário</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for _, record in check.iterrows %}
            <tr>
                {% for value in record %}
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
```

I would like to apply this htmldiff function (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/653/how-to-diff-html-compare-and-highlight-differences-and-generate-output-in-html-with-javascript), creating a third column where the highlight diff are going to be returned.

I can dynamically create a 'Diff' column, but I don't know how to populated that column.
Following the link above, the function can be called as the following:

```
// Diff HTML strings
let output = htmldiff(originalHTML, newHTML);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

Is there a way to return the function as a third column?
The working application can be find here https://jurisfai.herokuapp.com/documentcomparer/, I am trying to better the visualization creating a third column.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: If this question isn't meant to be about django, it might be better to remove the django template code and put the generated HTML there instead.  Anyway, I've added the "django" tag for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  To do this in JavaScript, you'll need to loop over the table rows, and reference the table cells to get/set the data.  Something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0];
for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var cells = table.rows[i].cells;
    cells[2].innerHTML = htmldiff(cells[0].innerHTML, cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```

It looks like your `htmldiff` function is in JavaScript, so this should work for you provided you add the third column somehow (either by sending an empty column from the server, or using one of the JavaScript functions that can add a cell to a table).

Comment: Can I do this to return as a secund column?  Because I just noticed the column that I add dynamically didn't work.

Comment: @victorcd Do I understand you right that you mean to add the column via JavaScript?  In that case you need to add a cell to every row, within the loop (in addition to adding the `th` element outside the loop).

Comment: Yeah, but I don't need another column if this is possible to do in the "arquivo secundario" column. If it wasn't I am thinking to "render" this column by the django. I am facing many difficulties to do this in the javascript. Thank you.

Comment: @victorcd You want to replace the contents of the second column with the diff?  Easy enough; just put the diff in `cells[1].innerHTML` instead of `cells[2].innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you, it works for the th. But I need to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at".

Comment: @victorcd that means one of the cells doesn't exist... which might be because your template is putting a `tr` inside of a `tr`.  (I think the outer one is supposed to be `tbody`.)

Comment: I've tried, but without success. Take a look above.

Comment: @victorcd [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/z97rqjfb/)

Comment: I also edited your question to show what I meant by changing the `tr` to a `tbody`.  (Questions should only have one problem in them anyway, and this problem of an extra `tr` is separate from the "how to do it" problem.)

Comment: I saw your jsfiddle example working fine, I've copied and made the neccessaries changes, but the same error is returned.

Comment: I forget the edit tbody in your jsfiddle. It works^^

Comment: this way is simpler than I thought. I am so happy to understand why it wasn't work. Thank you so much.